# How to Send Gravity Form Entry Data to aspx third party url

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, gravityforms

This is not a repeat question. I have this gravity forms addon which send data to third-party URL. Everything is working up to submitting the entry data. The third-party URL is  ASPX and the data is XML and is encoded to base64. So I try to use `$request = new WP_Http();
    $response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $data ) );` and check the ouput in the logs files I know it works the only problem is it will not redirect to the aspx url.

I try `curl` too same results.

I try using shortcodes but the problem is the data is not included in the forms no matter how I try.

anyway here's my code

[Gravityforms code](https://gist.github.com/rakethostph/b5a985a892e6ce8af869f3d1ab073275)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to this question so here the solutions.

Firsl Create a WordPress Filter

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_1', array( $this, 'paynamics_confirmation' ), 10, 3 );
```

then create a function `paynamics_confirmation` with 3 properties `$confirmation, $form, $entry`

```
public function paynamics_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $entry) { 
// From Settings
$paynamics_url  = $this->get_plugin_setting( 'paynamics_endpoint_url');
$data = $this->paynamics_data($entry, $form, $feed);
$confirmation = '<form name="paynamics_send" id="paynamics_send" method="post" name="paynamics_payment" action="'.$paynamics_url.'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="paymentrequest" id="paymentrequest" value="'.$data.'">
                        <div class="paynamics_button_wrapper" style="text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send To Paynamics" class="paynamics_button" id="paynamics_submit_button" style="background-color: #E46824;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 99px;">
                        </div>

                    </form>';
return $confirmation;

}
```